# Trouble centering Wordpress header elements with _s starter theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, centering, underscores-wp

My apologies if I'm missing something obvious here, but I'm having trouble centering my header elements.

I'm styling the elements within the header in `#site-navigation` so that I can use a `background-color` attribute that stretches to 100% of the width in `#masthead` without being cutoff.

To give you an idea, my logo and links are currently aligned left, however I'm not sure why.

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header">
    <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
        <a href="#"><!-- code for logo svg --></a>
        <span id="list-container"><!-- code for links (primary menu) --></span>
    </nav>
</header>
```

CSS

```
#masthead {
  background-color: #efefef;
  height: 100px;
  margin: -100px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#site-navigation {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 95%;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but isn't a simple `text-align: center` on `#site-navigation` sufficient enough to center the elements in the header?

Comment: that's not working unfortunately; I'm trying to centre my logo, and links in my header

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle, so I can understand what you're trying to do? On another note, it would be better if you put the links for the primary menu in a `<ul>` element and not in a `<span>` element :)

Comment: thanks for the advice, I will do that! I worked out that somewhere else in the code (in the _s theme on the class `.main-navigation`) `float: left` was applied so I used `float:  none` to centre it. I'm not sure how I could edit this question to be helpful to people.

Comment: Maybe add which template you're using and post the solution as an answer since you solved it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the _s (underscores) Wordpress starter theme, the class `.main-navigation` has the attribute `float: left`. So I used `float: none` in my header class to centre it.